# Faster way to convert from a String to generic type T when T is a valuetype?

Tags: vb.net, generics, type-conversion

Does anyone know of a fast way in VB to go from a string to a generic type `T` constrained to a valuetype (`Of T as Structure`), when I know that `T` will always be some number type?

This is too slow for my taste:

```
Return DirectCast(Convert.ChangeType(myStr, GetType(T)), T)
```

But it seems to be the only sane method of getting from a `String` --> `T`.  I've tried using Reflector to see how `Convert.ChangeType` works, and while I can convert from the String to a given number type via a hacked-up version of that code, I have no idea how to jam that type back into `T` so it can be returned.

I'll add that part of the speed penalty I'm seeing (in a timing loop) is because the return value is getting assigned to a `Nullable(Of T)` value.  If I strongly-type my class for a specific number type (i.e., `UInt16`), then I can vastly increase the performance, but then the class would need to be duplicated for each numeric type that I use.

It'd almost be nice if there was converter to/from `T` while working on it in a generic method/class.  Maybe there is and I'm oblivious to its existence?

**Conclusion**:
Testing the three provided implementations below and my original DirectCast/ChangeType form, @peenut's approach of using a prepared delegate to fetch the `Parse` method from a basic type works.  No error checking is done, however, so implementors need to remember to only use this with valuetypes that have a `Parse` method available.  Or extend the below to do error checking.

All runs were done on a 32bit system running Windows Server 2003 R2 with 4GB of RAM.  Each "run" is 1,000,000 executions (ops) of the method to be tested, timed with StopWatch and reported back in milliseconds.

Original `DirectCast(Convert.ChangeType(myStr, GetType(T)), T)`:

```
1000000 ops: 597ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 472ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 458ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 453ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 466ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 462ms
```

Using `System.Reflection` and calling `InvokeMethod` to get at the `Parse` method:

```
1000000 ops: 12213ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 11468ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 11509ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 11524ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 11509ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 11490ms
```

Konrad's approach to generate IL code to access the `Parse` method and store the call into a delegate:

```
1000000 ops: 352ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 316ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 315ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 314ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 314ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 314ms
```

peenut's approach of using a delegate to access the `Parse` method directly:

```
1000000 ops: 272ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 272ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 275ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 274ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 272ms
Average of 1000000 ops over 10 runs: 273ms
```

Comparatively, peenut's approach is almost 200ms faster when executed 1,000,000 times in a tight loop, so his approach wins out.  Although, Konrad's wasn't far behind and is itself a fascinating study of things like ILGenerator.  Props to all who contributed!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, I know about faster solution :-)

Faster solution is to use prepared delegate for given (generic) Type T. If you are only interested in String->(built-in numeric type), you can simply get Parse method with one argument (String).

Program to test speed of possibilities. Note that only first two methods are generic, 3rd and 4th methods are for comparison only.

```
Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1

    Public Class Parser(Of T As Structure)

        Delegate Function ParserFunction(ByVal value As String) As T

        Public Shared ReadOnly Parse2 As ParserFunction = GetFunction()

        Private Shared Function GetFunction() As ParserFunction
            Dim t As Type = GetType(T)
            Dim m As MethodInfo = t.GetMethod("Parse", New Type() {GetType(String)})
            Dim d As ParserFunction = DirectCast( _
               ParserFunction.CreateDelegate(GetType(ParserFunction), m),  _
               ParserFunction)
            Return d
        End Function


        Public Shared Function Parse1(ByVal value As String) As T
            Return DirectCast(Convert.ChangeType(value, GetType(T)), T)
        End Function
    End Class

    Sub Main()

        Dim w As New Stopwatch()

        'test data:
        Dim arrStr() As String = New String(12345678 - 1) {}
        Dim r As New Random
        For i As Integer = 0 To arrStr.Length - 1
            arrStr(i) = r.Next().ToString()
        Next
        Dim arrInt1() As Integer = New Integer(arrStr.Length - 1) {}
        Dim arrInt2() As Integer = New Integer(arrStr.Length - 1) {}


        Console.WriteLine("1. method - Convert.ChangeType:")
        w.Reset()
        w.Start()
        For i As Integer = 0 To arrStr.Length - 1
            arrInt1(i) = Parser(Of Integer).Parse1(arrStr(i))
        Next
        w.Stop()
        Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed)
        Console.WriteLine()

        Console.WriteLine("2. method - prepared delegate:")
        w.Reset()
        w.Start()
        For i As Integer = 0 To arrStr.Length - 1
            arrInt2(i) = Parser(Of Integer).Parse2(arrStr(i))
        Next
        w.Stop()
        Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed)
        Console.WriteLine()

        Console.WriteLine("3. method - Integer.Parse:")
        w.Reset()
        w.Start()
        For i As Integer = 0 To arrStr.Length - 1
            arrInt2(i) = Integer.Parse(arrStr(i))
        Next
        w.Stop()
        Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed)
        Console.WriteLine()

        Console.WriteLine("4. method - CType:")
        w.Reset()
        w.Start()
        For i As Integer = 0 To arrStr.Length - 1
            arrInt2(i) = CType(arrStr(i), Integer)
        Next
        w.Stop()
        Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed)
        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

You can change number of tested elements, if you want. I used 12345678 random integers. Program outputs for me:

```
1. method - Convert.ChangeType:
00:00:03.5176071

2. method - prepared delegate:
00:00:02.9348792

3. method - Integer.Parse:
00:00:02.8427987

4. method - CType:
00:00:05.0542241
```

Ratio of times: 3.5176071 / 2.9348792 = 1.20

Comment: Damn you, I was about to post that same solution. :-(

Comment: Yeah, there should be "lock question privilege" that would mean: I'm good, I know the answer, don't bother... No kidding, go and suggest this somewhere.

Comment: @peenut: nonsense. You were faster (and I only knew the solution because I’d found a reference to `Delegate.CreateDelegate` somewhere else on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Delegates are really hard on the eyes when you're new to them.

Comment: Help me understand this somewhat...I know that `Delegate Function ParserFunction(ByVal value As String) As T` is like a pointer to a function in C.  But why have `Parse2` as a public shared property that simply fetches the Private non-shared `GetFunction()` function?  Couldn't one just bypass this step and make `GetFunction` shared and public?  Only key difference is the use of `ReadOnly`, which isn't usable on a function declaration, so if it's done this way as a protection mechanism, then I get it.

Comment: @peenut: Yours is indeed faster.  not by much over Konrad's, but looped enough and timed, it eventually beats his out.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is some kind of error checking to enforce the existence of the `Parse` method on `T`.  But at the same time, anyone using a solution as advanced as this should know better.

Comment: Agreed with Kumba here. The real degree of delegate in this delegate solution is the line `ParserFunction.CreateDelegate(GetType(ParserFunction), m)`. I am confused as to why bother an extra layer of delegate with `Parse2 As  ParserFunction`, when everything could go inside a public function. Unless the point is to save resources for `ParseMethod = MyType.GetMethod()`? Also, I find `ParserFunction.CreateDelegate` confusing, because - as I understand - `CreateDelegate` does not rely on anything coming from `ParserFunction.`; if I am not mistaken, `[Delegate].CreateDelegate()` achieves the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a different approach that uses the `DynamicMethod` mentioned before.

Again, I couldn’t test the VB code (the Mono compiler chokes on the test call, though not on the code itself) but I believe it’s correct. Its C# equivalent works and the below code is a 1:1 translation:

```
public class Parser(of T as Structure)
    delegate function ParserFunction(value as String) as T
    private shared readonly m_parse as ParserFunction

    shared sub new()
        dim tt as Type = gettype(T)
        dim argumentTypes as Type() = new Type() { gettype(String) }
        dim typeDotParse as MethodInfo = tt.GetMethod("Parse", argumentTypes)
        dim method as new DynamicMethod("Parse", tt, argumentTypes)

        dim il as ILGenerator = method.GetILGenerator()
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeDotParse)
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)

        m_parse = directcast( _
            method.CreateDelegate(gettype(ParserFunction)), _
            ParserFunction)
    end sub

    public shared function Parse(byval value As String) As T
        return m_parse(value)
    end function
end class
```

This code can be cleared up if you have a recent version of VB. Again, the Mono compiler doesn’t yet know `Option Infer` and the likes.

What this code does is compile a separate parsing method for each code it’s called for. This parsing method merely delegates the actual parsing to the shared `T.Parse` method of the type (e.g. `Integer.Parse`). Once compiled, this code doesn’t require any additional casting, no boxing and no `Nullable`s.

The code is called as follows:

```
Dim i As Integer = Parser(Of Integer).Parse("42")
```

Apart from the one-time overhead for compilation, this method should be the fastest possible since there is no other overhead: just a function call to the actual parsing routine. It doesn’t get faster than that.

Comment: I'll have to test this later on today...I think you also gave me another answer to a question I haven't thought of asking yet -- inline IL (in a sense).

Comment: Also to add, could this can passed into a generic class, such that I have something like `myNum = Parser(Of T).Parse(myStr)` when I constrain T to `Structure` and not suffer any speed penalties?

Comment: @Kumba: yes, it can. That was the whole purpose, wasn’t it? ;-) It will however fail at runtime if the type `T` doesn’t have a public shared `Parse` method (but all the basic types do).

Comment: Yeah, constraining `T` to a 'Structure' should take care of that.  Worst case, one could wrap it in a `Try...Catch` block if one wants to risk eating the performance hit should that ever fire.

Comment: @Konrad: The code above fails in VS 2010 with an innerException, citing `Calling convention must be varargs.`.  Not a lot of hits on Google for such an exception message, so I am in the dark a little.  It fails specifically on the line `il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeDotParse, argumentTypes)`.

Comment: Wrong, you don't need to create new function, you already have the one you need - Parse. Look at my solution ;-)

Comment: @Kumba: I’ve fixed a bug, try again (but peenut’s solution is better!). The error was that `EmitCall` only works for vararg functions (this is even documented, I had somehow missed that) … for all other functions, a normal `Emit` is enough. I had tested the code on Mono and there the `EmitCall` method works even though it’s documented not to.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl (and peenut's, too) later on.  Thanks!  Also sounds like you've found a Mono bug.  I have plans to test my project out on Mono when I get farther ahead to see how Linux-compatible it'll be.  Should be "interesting".  Even if both solutions work, it's a pity we can't assign "partial answers", like on Experts Exchange...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an answer, another question instead. What will you achieve by having this method. Let's imagine you somehow implemented such method (Sorry for C# in Vb.Net post, but hopefully you'll get the idea):

```
T Convert<T>(string strInput) { ... }
```

and you will use this method only for limited range of types: double, int, Int16, etc. So you will use it like this:

```
double x = Convert<double>(myStr);
```

I do not see any benefit in such method, because for the same reason without that method you would write:

```
double x = double.Parse(myStr);
```

So what I'm trying to say is that without your magic method you will write the same amount of code to use it. I do not see any benefit of that method. Am I missing some use-case?

Comment: I think you missed what I am trying to do.  Assume a generic method `Public Function Foo(Of T As Structure)(ByVal str As String) As T`.  I have to return type `T`, presumably to a variable in a generic class (`Dim tmp As T`).  If in `Foo`, I do `Dim tmpDbl As Double = Double.Parse(str)`, then when I try to `Return tmpDbl`, the IDE will throw an error because Double cannot be converted to `T`.  Hence the `DirectCast`/`Convert.ChangeType` combo outlined in my original post which is slow.

Comment: Thanks, that's the point I was missing - that this generic can be used in other generic classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have a VB compiler so I can’t test it but the following works in C#. I doubt that it’s faster though, since it’s using reflection:

```
Public Shared Function Parse(Of T As Strcture)(ByVal value As String) As T
    Dim type = GetType(T)
    Dim result = type.InvokeMember( _
        "Parse", _
        BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, _
        Nothing, Nothing, new Object() { value })
    Return DirectCast(result, T)
End Function
```

One way to speed this up is to create a dynamic method from the `T.Parse` member instead of `InvokeMember` and cache that dynamic method for each type. This would mean a bigger overhead for the first call (compiling a dynamic method) but subsequent runs would be faster.

Comment: Wrong, you don't need to create new function, you already have the one you need - Parse. Look at my solution ;-)